# How do I make a direct link to execute an .hta file?

Tags: javascript, windows, browser, hta

I have an .hta file on a mapped drive that I can manually navigate to, double-click on the .hta file and it executes fine.  However, I added a link to the full path on the share (from an IE 8 page) and when I try to run it from the link, as in:

Q:\path...\.hta

Then I get a javascript error an error occurred in running the script "length is null or not an object".  The javascript code is coming from the .hta file itself on this line:

```
...
for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) { 
...
```

I'm guessing that for some reason "i" isn't initialized when the .hta is run off the link, rather than manually.

In any event, when I try to directly go to the file from the link, I do get a dialog asking if I want to run, save, or cancel the .hta file.  When I try to run it, I get the javascript error.

So my questions are:

1. how do I run this .hta file from a browser link?
2. why do I get the javascript error when run from a link and not when it's run manually?

Comment: When you click the browser link, does it ask you to run the .hta, or does it navigate to the physical path in your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTA does not recognize mapped drives.

I assume you have your application saved at server, and then you run it at workstation, where you have this mapped driver `Q` as a shortcut to the server.

The correct path to server is something like this:

```
//Your_Server_Name/path_in_server/file.hta
```

An actual IP can also be used instead of the `Your_Server_Name`.

To run the HTA in browser (IE only) without prompts, you'll need to change many settings in Intranet zone security- and Advanced-tab to very insecure mode.

About the error message:

It seems, that `matches` has not a property named `length`. If `matches` is defined, it's probably a number or a boolean, or some other type of object which has not the `length` property.

If the message is something like this: `Can't get the property length: object is null or not defined`. This means, that `matches` is undefined.

Notice, that HTA is an independent application with it's own `top.window`, and it can't interact with the browser window. (There is no way to refer the `opener` in HTA, if the opener is a browser window.)

Comment: Yes, we are running in IE only, but I don't care about getting a prompt.  matches is a var that uses str.match with a regex.  Q is actually just a mapped drive where the .hta resides.  IE runs in a VDI environment and just goes directly to the mapped drive in the anchor reference.